# Osculating plane<=>distance limit

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $r$ be a unit-speed bi-regular curve. (It passes the point $s_0$)
Let $distP(q)$ be the distance between the plane $P$ and the point $q$.

Question.

The plane is equal to the osculating plane of $r$ at $s_0$ if and only if
$P$ contains 
$r(s_0)$,$$ \lim_{s \to s_0} \frac{distP(r(s))}{(s-s_0)} = 0$$
$$\lim_{s \to s_0} \frac{distP(r(s))}{(s-s_0)^2} =0$$

Comment: Any attempt at all?

Comment: First limit is easy; since P contains the tangent line of r. You can just use the equation a•(X-P)/|a| to get the distP(r(s)) and find out that limit is really zero.

Comment: You should always put an attempt into the question. The members of Stack exchange are likely to down-vote questions not showing any attempt.

Comment: Okay, it might look dirty. By using the distance formula, distP(r(s))/(s-s0)^2=|r'Xr"|•(r(s)-r(s0))/|r'Xr"|(s-s0)^2. Here I can't advance more. Stucked.

Comment: I think "unit speed curve" can be an important key, but I don't know where to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Using the L'Hospital's law, the equation means that the binormal vector of r(s) perpendicular to the normal vector. And it is true because it is bi-regular curve.